# POWER BI How to create a data table for a histogram

Tags: datatable, pivot, powerbi, histogram, transpose

I have been unable to locate any instructions on how to create the standard data table for a histogram or instructions on how to pivot a data table visual by using a date field(column) as the headers.

Below is a simple example of what I need.  Excel calls this a data table.  If it is called something else in PowerBI I can't figure it out.

Ultimately, I just need to transpose the relevant data from row format to Column format, but I prefer not to do this for the whole table in the background.  I'd prefer to do it just for this visual and leave the background data in its current format for other visuals.

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is called "Show as a table", you can get it from the "..." menu in the top-right corner of any visual.

It's documented here, although a little out-of-date currently:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-show-data

FWIW that looks like a clustered column chart, not a histogram. With a histogram, the X axis is typically made up of buckets of a numeric value, whereas your example shows dates.

Comment: 10/4 on the clustered column.  Regarding the data table, while this is a useful table it is not in the desired format.  The question is how do I show the table pivoted by date.  The "Show as a table" table is in the standard data format with dates in records instead of fields.  I'm looking for the dates to be headers as shown in the diagram above instead of as records shown vertically.  Is there a way to transpose or pivot this data in the "Show as a table"?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.